# How many containers and state should I have in a real world big application?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to the `Redux`, but I like it very much. The single store is really awesome for SPA. But I have a question for a real world big application.

For example, if there is a membership management application. We have login page, member management page and accounting page. Should I have 3 `states` for each page? If I still have one single `state`, my concern is that the `state` is going to be huge.

Should I have 3 containers for each page? If we need a new page, such as AddMember page. Should I add a new container?

Should I remove the data from `state` tree on each containers's `unmounted` method?

I have checked the examples provided in the source code. Most of them are only for a small SPA. Is there a big application scaffold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reducers and state**

You only ever have a single state in Redux. But you can easily break it down into smaller substates with reducers. Say you have a directory called reducers/ with a file index.js, it might look like this:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import login from './login';
import member from './member';
import accounting from './accounting';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    login,
    member,
    accounting
});

export default rootReducer;
```

The files login.js, member.js and accounting.js would have their own reducer functions and only need be aware of their own piece of the state.

Quite how you break up your state into separate reducers is up to you. This is just a suggestion. It may not be appropriate to do it in this manner if the pages have lots of overlapping state.

I suggest reading up on reducers here.
http://rackt.org/redux/docs/basics/Reducers.html

**Containers (or smart components)**

When you ask how many containers, I assume you mean smart components. That is, React components that connect to Redux. As a starting point, I would suggest only connecting your root component, and passing down (parts of) the state via props.

However if you're using React Router, you'll need to connect each of your route handlers, which will each take their own slice of the state.

For more on connecting, see the react-redux docs. https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/master/docs/quick-start.md#quick-start

Comment: Thanks for your good answer. I still have a one question if we use single state in whole application. If a user navigates from member page to the accounting page, I think most of the member page state data should be removed since we don't need them any more. Is that true? If so, do I have to do it manually in the member reducer?

Comment: I don't think you necessarily do want that data removed. If you need that data again when they navigate back to the member page then it's best left in there. Alternatively, If some of the state needs to be reset when they transition from the page, you could create an action that resets the data. (Perhaps you're worried about memory bloat. I wouldn't be concerned. Memory is cheap. The memory footprint of Redux is surely trivial compared to that of React.)

Comment: Yes, I am a little worry about the memory since our application will have a lot of tables. Thousands of records in each page.  In a traditional app, we are doing the pagination. For Redux, I think each page's data is store in the state tree once it been loaded into the the page. I don't know whether Redux is good for that kind of application.

Comment: In that case, you probably want to load in the data asynchronously and keep track of the page number in the state. The way to do async in redux is in an action creator using redux-thunk and an AJAX library. (I tend to use superagent as my AJAX library.) There are examples in the redux-thunk readme. https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk